# Different instance repr based on logging level

Tags: python, logging

I'd like to log information about some instance. However, I want to show different levels of detail depending on the log level I'm using. For example:

```py
LOGGER.level
# => 20
LOGGER.info('Car info: %s', Car())
# => [INFO]: Car info: Celica
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
LOGGER.info('Car info: %s', Car())
# => [INFO]: Car info: {'name': 'Celica', 'year': 1998, 'model': 'GT-Four'}
```

So far, I came up with something like the following:

```py
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(
    format='[%(levelname)s]: %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO)
    
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Celica'
        self.year = 1998
        self.model = 'GT-Four'

    def __repr__(self):
        if LOGGER.level == logging.DEBUG:
            return str(self.__dict__)
            
        return f'{self.name}'
```

I have the feeling that this is a bit too "custom" and hardcoded, somehow. Using `LOGGER` or `logging` in `__repr__` feels a bit odd. Is this the correct way to proceed, or is there a better way?

Comment: One argument against this approach is that his only differentiates based on a specific logger and the baseconfig is was created with. In complex scenarios with a hierarchy of logger and different loglevels set, this wont work well.

Comment: A completely different approach that also provides ways to control the information logged and how they are represented could be [structlog](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/).

Comment: @Markus so would you say there is no straightforward way to achieve what I want and still keep a certain flexibility in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be unusual logic to have in a `__repr__` - perhaps a code smell, as you've identified. Normally presentation logic would be placed in a `Formatter` subclass, but you could also do it in a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=resort#filter-objects). Here's a simple working example; you should be able to adapt the basic idea into a more general scheme:

```
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Celica'
        self.year = 1998
        self.model = 'GT-Four'

def filter(record):
    if record.args:
        args = []
        for arg in record.args:
            if isinstance(arg, Car):
                if record.levelno == logging.DEBUG:
                    arg = str(arg.__dict__)
                else:
                    arg = arg.name
            args.append(arg)
        record.args = tuple(args)
    return True

def main():
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    f = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)-5s]: %(message)s')
    h = logging.StreamHandler()
    h.setFormatter(f)
    LOGGER.addHandler(h)
    LOGGER.addFilter(filter)
    car = Car()
    LOGGER.info('basic : %s', car)
    LOGGER.debug('detail: %s', car)
    LOGGER.debug('no car in this %s', 'message')
    LOGGER.debug('nor in this one')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When run, the above script prints:

```
[INFO ]: basic : Celica                                              
[DEBUG]: detail: {'name': 'Celica', 'year': 1998, 'model': 'GT-Four'}
[DEBUG]: no car in this message                                      
[DEBUG]: nor in this one
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This seems way cleaner, and I feel like it's much better than the `__repr__` approach. Do you think this kind of filter would interfere with performance, somehow? Or do you think it's negligible? (I suppose it really depends on the amount of logging you do, but I'd still like to hear your opinion).

Comment: @KurtBourbaki  I don't think the overhead will be all that high (compared to I/O times) but obviously any overhead can matter, depending on the exact circumstances. I would say, definitely worth trying. Certainly (as logging maintainer) I can't recall seeing issues raised about filtering overhead.